# mysqldump: Error 1412: Table definition has changed, please retry transaction when dumping table

Tags: mysql

When we run the sqldump we got the error below on two tables:

mysqldump: Error 1412: Table definition has changed, please retry transaction when dumping table ''

We had run the check tabl is OK.

On the global log there is no Delete or Truncate on the same time as our sqldump.

Thank you for your help

Best Regards,

We had run the check tabl is OK.

On the global log there is no Delete or Truncate on the same time as our sqldump

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ref cli:
`mysqldump -uroot -proot -P3306 --single-transaction --master-data=2 --flush-logs --flush-privileges --routines --events  --triggers db01 > D:\mysql_backup\db01.sql`